# Prepend line to stdout in Python in attempt to display falling drops animation

Tags: python, console, stdout

How to prepend lines to stdout ?

In other words, when I write to stdout I want the output that was already printed to be 'pushed' down, then prepend next output.

Comment: Would you be able to show us your code or describe in more details what is your use case for that.

Comment: It will look like a book written with the lines in reverse order. It's not very user-friendly.

Comment: I actually want to simulate drops falling in the console. But, the 'why' is not important :) the 'how' is what I am asking ?

Comment: Why is very important since it dictates how to approach the problem.

Comment: Are you in linux? You could play with the curses module.

Comment: you can't seek() in stdout so you can't do what you ask.

Comment: yes in linux ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that simply by manupulating stdout directly. Stdout is a file object. In regular file objects `seek` can be used. However, since everything is displayed in terminal as quickly as they get written to it, calling seek doesn't affect what has already been displayed.

However, with a proper terminal library like [curses](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) you can output control characters that manipulate cursor position and allows you to change text content anywhere in the console.

Note that curses is pretty low level library. For your specific use case of making animations, it might make sense to use a higher-level library like [asciimatics](https://github.com/peterbrittain/asciimatics).

Comment: There are also other libraries, mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349085/python-ncurses-cdk-urwid-difference).

Answer (score 0):

- Store the initial value to list,
- then until your condition is satisfied,

  - append the new content to list
- join the data with '\n'

That is,

```
import sys
arr = ['start line',]
while some_condition_till_you_want_to_write:
    arr.append('some new content')
print "\n".join(arr)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I need to do this continuously

Comment: to do this continuously, put True for while block and use queue inside. if queue is not empty fetch items from queue and print them, else don't print.
And write a function, which will put the items inside the queue.